# How to post Facebook Application request from Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk

Currently I am using Facebook c# SDK for my windowsphone7 application..,
I created friend list from which friend(thats facebook UID) is selected to send application request .
This is my code

```
arguments["access_token"] = "Accesstoken";
arguments["message"] = "message";
arguments["IDS"] = "IDS";
facebook.PostAsync("me/apprequests", arguments);
facebook.PostCompleted += facebook_PostCompleted;
```

But still request didn't post on facebook user profile.

Comment: Do you want to post some text on the news feed?

Comment: Yes,I want to send Application request from my WP7 to User wall

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct so my guess is that you don't have the correct permissions. Have you asked the user for the publish_stream extended permission when you authenticate?

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/